# Capturing wireless traffic (using Wireshark)

Tags: wireless-networking, network-adapter, wireshark, sniffing, packet

When I run wireshark on a wired network it works fine and reports all of the packets.
When I run it on a wireless network though I only see my own traffic.  The wireless card I have is supposed to support packet capture and go into premiscous mode, but I don't see any other system traffic.

What is wrong?

Comment: I am having the same problem.  Running latest wireshark 1.8.6 on a Macbook Pro capturing wifi packets, if I enable monitor mode I can see all kinds of traffic but I can't tell what it is, because it says everything is an 802.11 packet (it doesn't decode them into TCP/IP).  If I disable monitor mode I can see only my own traffic.  Any help?

Comment: You're probably on an encrypted (WEP/WPA) network.  In order to dissect the traffic, it would have to be encrypted; see [the Wireshark Wiki page about decrypting 802.11 traffic](http://wiki.wireshark.org/HowToDecrypt802.11).  (After all, the whole point of encrypting Wi-Fi networks is to make it harder to sniff the network!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at [Wi-Fi (WLAN, IEEE 802.11)](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Wi-Fi) on the Wireshark Wiki page.

> See the [CaptureSetup/WLAN](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/WLAN) page for instructions how to capture from WLAN's (including monitor mode), and see the [CaptureSetup](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup) page for general information on capturing on WLAN's and other media.

Going further, if you are using Windows (are you?)

> Capturing WLAN traffic on Windows depends on [WinPcap](http://wiki.wireshark.org/WinPcap) and on the underlying network adapters and drivers. Unfortunately, most drivers/adapters support neither monitor mode, nor seeing 802.11 headers when capturing, nor capturing non-data frames.
>
> Promiscuous mode can be set; unfortunately, it's often crippled. In this mode many drivers don't supply packets at all, or don't supply packets sent by the host.
> If you experience any problems capturing packets on WLANs, try to switch promiscuous mode off. In this case you will have to capture traffic on the host you're interested in.
>
> The [AirPcap](http://www.cacetech.com/products/airpcap_family.htm) adapters from [CACE Technologies](http://www.cacetech.com/) allow full raw 802.11 captures under Windows, including radiotap information.

Here is another reference you might want to read up.
[A Quick Intro to Sniffers](http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=security/AQuickIntrotoSniffers):
<sup>Wireshark/Ethereal, ARPSpoof, Ettercap, ARP poisoning and other niceties.</sup>

Comment: Does it work in Linux better?

Comment: @Daisetsu, I believe so. Have not tried it there myself. Maybe, someone else here has first hand experience...

Comment: Just an FYI for anyone wanting to order airPcap Cace NX3 pack. I ordered their 3 pack package over three weeks ago and still haven't received it. The third party I'm ordering though has been trying daily to get this in my hands. I still haven't received the package and I have a very important network test on Sunday. This company really screwed me and I'll never forget. I have the choice of going with OmniPeak Pro, Fluke, or AirPcap Cace NX3 pack. I decided to go with AirPcap Case NX 3 because of the reviews I've seen on the internet. I work with very complex wireless systems and will never for